# How can i delete a uv map in the img editor

Tags: uv

so i have a model with couple different uv islands and i was wondering is there a way to unwrap the model and delete a uv island in the img editor? 
I unwrapped the whole model and am trying to delete a uv island..

Comment: Hello :). I'm afraid you cannot really delete a part of a UV map. The whole object is either unwrapped, or not unwrapped. What are you trying to achieve? Maybe there's a better way.